# Differences in experience gain in mutliplayer in comparison to my friend

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm leveling up a lot quicker, I'd say around 25%, than my friend when we play together.

I'm playing Engi he is playing Embermage. We both don't have any +exp skills, items or spells and only quest together within experience range.

Any clue what might cause this?

---

Mainly asking because it's annoying for him to also "level alone" to get on my level again.

Comment: could it be that you are doing most of the killing compared to your friend?  there doesn't seem to be much info so far on party experience information

Comment: @yx I'm playing "tank" and he does most of the damage. He has over 5000 kills (in the stats using "j") and I have only 380.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the experience distribution is based on the damage dealt and not necessarily kills.

Comment: @JeffMercado He's doing pretty much all the damage. His damage dealt numbers are a factor of 100 bigger than mine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not alone. A friend and I have been playing in the same configuration. I'm the embermage, he's the engineer. He's constantly outleveling me. I have about 82k kills versus his 10k, and neither of us are using EXP-boosting items.

From what a couple people testing this have said, EXP is not split equally among the party members. The person who is standing idly by receives more experience than the player killing the monster.

It appears that this is a bug. [From a post from a Runic staff member](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?p=339617#p339617), they said they believe they know what is causing it. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.